# Variable Font TTF and Fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I'm having trouble getting correct font weights (optical or otherwise) with Fraunces from Google Fonts (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fraunces) and LuaTeX. It's a variable font!

The output is a big thick font, and I can't figure out the right arguments to fontspec to give the output appropriate weights (manually or automatically)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={+axis={wght=100}}}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[
  Kerning=On,
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,
  Path           = ./, % Directory of the fonts
  UprightFont    = *,
  ItalicFont     = *Italic,
  UprightFeatures = {RawFeature={+axis={wght=100}} },
  BoldFeatures = { RawFeature={+axis={wght=100} }},
]{Fraunces}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  
  \headingfont
  \Large Some Text  \\
  \medskip
  \normalsize More Text
  \vfill
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your output and the .log file? This is what I get (after removing the custom path and the italic option): https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4TfK.png